# Not credited in paper written by boss

Tags: publications, ethics, authorship, industry

I'm a contractor hired by a software engineering company that is branching out into research. For the last two years I have been working almost solo on a research project for the company. A number of other people have come to help out on the project at some point or another, but currently all code in the codebase is written 100% by me. All of the novelties developed throughout the project were also done solo.

My boss has just written a research paper about the project which has been accepted by a low-tier journal. I got to read the paper today and while a number of my coworkers are credited, I am not. The credits consist of every non-contractor that has touched the project, as well as a number of higher ups in the company.

Furthermore, I created a number of figures used in the paper and edited the abstract.

Is this standard practice? Would it be reasonable to ask to be included in the authors list?

Edit: Just to update, my boss said that he had me in the authors list on the first draft, but when he ran it by my contracting company they said to take it off. I'm following up with them now.

Comment: If the authors are not interested, then with all the evidence of your contribution contact the editor of the journal... That should get results - however one result may well be an end of future contracts...

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah, I like this job and I'd rather not get authorship than lose it.

Comment: The edit certainly changes things, thanks for adding that. Unfortunately it seems like this also makes it a bit off-topic for Academia.SE because this seems to be more of an issue with your employer than any academic norms.

Comment: Time to change contracting company - no respect for you or your capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

As a contractor you may have explicitly or implicitly given over all of your intellectual product to the company. If that is the case then what they did is (minimally) acceptable. But in human terms it may not be proper. Certainly not "neighborly".

Since you indicate that there is a difference in how contractors and non-contractors were treated there may be some underlying justification, valid or not, for what was done.

I suspect that the practice is pretty common, but not universal.

However, it would be reasonable to ask for an acknowledgement at least, and maybe authorship. You can ask, at least. You might be refused and you might be given reasons why refusal is necessary, but you gain nothing from silence. At a minimum you will learn whether it is in your best interest to continue under such a relationship.

Comment: Intellectual property ownership is orthogonal to ethical authorship, IMHO. Most university staff also sign over IP ownership to their universities, yet nobody would claim that the top manager at the university should be the sole author on everything their institution produces.

Often companies publish something reports under the name of the company, rather than the authors - but if named individuals are being listed as authors, then the usual rules about authorship should apply.

Comment: @Flyto, yes, I agree. But what _should_ be and what _is_ aren't always properly aligned.

Comment: oh, absolutely, but that doesn't make what they did "minimally acceptable" ;-)

Comment: @Flyto,  unless you sign a contract. That was my point, actually. Be careful of what you sign. Always.

Comment: but that is also my point, that that would not make things OK. *Owning the IP output of my work does not make it OK to deny me credit* (except perhaps where the company gets credit - but that is clearly not the case here). The two are different things. I'm not sure what the legal situation is on the latter, but to my mind the ethical one - what is "acceptable" - is very clear.

Comment: I checked over my contract, and it doesn't say anything about intellectual property. Not sure about my country's laws specifically, though (Japan).

Answer (score 0):

My personal view is that this is unethical, and that if there are named authors - rather than it being published under the name of the company - then it would be reasonable for you to ask to be included, probably as an author. Authorship does not come only from writing the text of a paper, but from the intellectual contribution to the work that it describes, and from what you have said it sounds as though you provided most of the innovation that is being written about.